# How can I get the length of segments from the output of pgr_dijkstra?

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, osm2pgrouting

I created a topology from OSM data with `osm2pgrouting`.

I use a very simple Query

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT gid AS id,
         source,
         target,
         cost_s AS cost,
         reverse_cost_s AS reverse_cost
        FROM ways',
    13224, 9224, directed := true);
```

Which works fine. However, I am also interested in the length of the segments.

The `ways` table has a column `length_m` so I though I add this columns to the nested `SELECT`

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT gid AS id,
         source,
         target,
         length_m,
         cost_s AS cost,
         reverse_cost_s AS reverse_cost
        FROM ways',
    13224, 9224, directed := true);
```

However, the resulting table does not contain a column with the `length` of the segment.

Assuming I imported OSM data with `osm2pgrouting`. Would a join with the `ways` table gives me the desired output?

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT gid AS id,
         source,
         target,
         length_m,
         cost_s AS cost,
         reverse_cost_s AS reverse_cost
        FROM ways',
    13224, 9224, directed := true) AS route
INNER JOIN ways w
ON route.node = w.gid;
```

Two question: Is the `join` the right way to get the desired information (length of the routing segments).

And: I wonder why I cannot select the stuff within the `pgr_dijkstra()`?

***edit:**
The proper way to join the tables should be

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
    SELECT gid AS id,
         source,
         target,
         length_m,
         cost_s AS cost,
         reverse_cost_s AS reverse_cost
        FROM ways',
    13224, 9224, directed := true) AS route
LEFT JOIN ways w
ON route.edge = w.gid;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pgr_dijkstra(edges_sql, start_vid,  end_vid, directed:=true )` is a [SQL function](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/dijkstra/doc/pgr_dijkstra.html). It returns the following, regardless of what you input into its `TEXT edges_sql` argument.

```
RETURNS SET OF (seq, path_seq, node, edge, cost, agg_cost)
```

To answer your first question: **yes**, joining will be the only way you can get information from an external table to be added to the results.

Comment: okay. Assuming I imported my network with `osm2pgrouting`. The tables this framework creates are all the same. Would my join be ok?

Comment: yes, your join is ok.

Comment: @kttii I think the join was wrong. I edited my Q. Further: Is the unit of the `cost_s` column, created through `osm2pgrouting`, seconds? What unit is the `cost` column (also created through `osm2pgrouting`) then? I cannot find anything in the docs on that.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to post a new question please?

Comment: @Stophface basically though, cost is derived from length divided by speed (or km / kph)

Comment: @kttii thanks. I am missing a good documentation on how the columns are created... What happens if in the speed column, the `maxspeed` (https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:maxspeed) is `mph` or `kmh`? Further, is the speed in `maxspeed_forward` the speed from `key:maxspeed`? If there is no value in the cell, will the default `maxspeed` from the `config.xml` be used? That should be written somewhere in the documentation to make sense of the data...